# tidyr/data.table: gather/melt only values, discard keys

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, tidyr

I want to gather/melt a data frame that doesnt have a key, value final output. All values should end into one column.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

data <- get_sentiments("nrc")
```

The data I work with looks like this:
    nrc_wide <- dcast(nrc, word ~ sentiment)

```
# sample output:

         word anger anticipation disgust fear  joy negative positive 
1      abacus  <NA>         <NA>    <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    
2     abandon  <NA>         <NA>    <NA> fear <NA> negative     <NA> 
3   abandoned anger         <NA>    <NA> fear <NA> negative     <NA> 
4 abandonment anger         <NA>    <NA> fear <NA> negative     <NA>
```

I wish to turn it into what the original set looked like:

```
     word sentiment
     <chr>     <chr>
1    abacus     trust
2   abandon      fear
3   abandon  negative
4   abandon   sadness
```

I have tried many gather and melt options but this is not a key value format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A normal `tidyr::gather` operation should do, except you need 1) drop NAs with `na.rm = TRUE`; 2) exclude `word` column while reshaping so it stays; 3) drop the key column after:

```
library(tidyverse)
nrc_wide %>% 
    gather(key, sentiment, -word, na.rm = T) %>% 
    select(-key) %>% 
    arrange(word) %>% 
    head

#       word sentiment
#1    abacus     trust
#2   abandon      fear
#3   abandon  negative
#4   abandon   sadness
#5 abandoned     anger
#6 abandoned      fear
```

---

Use `data.table::melt`:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(nrc_wide), id.vars = "word", na.rm = TRUE)[, 
    .(word, sentiment = value)
][order(word)]

#            word    sentiment
#    1:    abacus        trust
#    2:   abandon         fear
#    3:   abandon     negative
#    4:   abandon      sadness
#    5: abandoned        anger
#   ---                       
#13897:      zest anticipation
#13898:      zest          joy
#13899:      zest     positive
#13900:      zest        trust
#13901:       zip     negative
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!